# What is a suitable workflow for cutting down trees?

Tags: trees, forests

I have many trees on my land that need to be cut down. I would like to know what suitable workflows there are for the whole process. Should I cut a tree down, cut it up into small pieces, and split the pieces to make firewood all in one step? Or should I cut many trees down and move them to a separate area to process the wood? I would like efficiency to be a high priority.

NOTE: Assume the following equipment - 5x8 trailer with winch, 18" chainsaw, sledge hammer, splitting axe. 10-15 trees. All are 50' or taller. They range from 10"-18" in diameter. I have all summer to do this. There will be at most 2-3 people working at a time.

Comment: Would this question be better suited to Gardening and Landscaping? http://gardening.stackexchange.com Or is it entirely too subjective anyway?

Comment: @renesis Gardening and Landscaping, this guy is deforesting, The great outdoors is its place

Comment: @Erik Efficient time wise. I want this to be completely diy, no hired crew.

Comment: @renesis I felt that this would be better suited for Outdoors since it could help people get an idea for efficient firewood collecting when in the outdoors/camping/surviving. Also seemed a bit more hardcore for Gardening and Landscaping.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a gardening question.  The 5x8 trailer, chainsaw and sledge are equipment that are not likely to be carried when out on a trip.

Comment: @Phil I feel like this could fall under the "Outdoorsmanship" aspect of this site. Regardless, if this is not appropriate for this site, I will gladly move this to the Gardening SE.

Comment: Yeah, not trying to undermine your question, just wondering if you may get a better answer elsewhere.

Comment: @renesis I certainly understand your point, but I feel it is on topic because it feels like a "lumberjack skills" question. In my own mind lumberjack skills are more in line with rugged traditional outdoorsman skills than domestic chores like gardening and landscaping. By domestic I mean "around the house" not some sideways slur against gardening and landscaping. Gardening and landscaping are real skills that often involve arduous labor.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really about the great outdoors.  The best forum/board may be home improvement, or perhaps gardening.  This question is much closer to "How do I quickly build a fence" than it is to anything regarding any of the outdoor hobbies discussed on this site.

Comment: For those that are interested there is now a [meta question](http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/719/7995) about this question.

Comment: I voted to reopen this question because it doesn't sound like any gardening or landscaping project I've seen.  It sounds more like the first step in 19th century homesteading.  When preparation for "landscaping" is done on this scale, it involves big machinery, not two or three guys with chainsaws.   What does the access road look like?  If it is unpaved, unimproved dirt with lots of rocks and ruts, it is definitely a TGO question!

Comment: The trees are on private land. There is a road to the land but nothing on the land itself. Basically the only access for vehicles would be via ATV's or other off-road vehicles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the purpose of my answer I'm going to assume there aren't any special considerations like a tall tree on a small lot.

In general I think this is the best procedure:

1. Cut down one tree.
2. Trim off all the branches.
3. Build a big pile of small branches that aren't useful for firewood.

   a. Load this stuff into a trailer and dispose of it as appropriate when you have a full trailer worth.

   b. Alternatively you can run this stuff through a wood chipper and sell/use the chips.
4. Cut the bigger branches into a length that will fit in your and/or your customer's fireplace comfortably.
5. Cut the trunk into rounds the same length as the branches in step 4.
6. Load the rounds/branches into the trailer once you have a trailer full.
7. Stack the rounds at your house.
8. Repeat the steps 1 through 7 until you've cut the amount of wood you need and/or you need to use some firewood.
9. Split the rounds and put them into a different stack.
10. Repeat the cycle as needed.

The main benefits of this plan are:

- You don't risk leaving wood to rot on the ground because something comes up.
- You can split wood in the evenings at home on days when you couldn't go out and cut down trees.
- You have some shade while you're chopping up the tree into manageable bits.
- You don't risk having too much wood at once.
- The animals can still use the trees until you need them.
- You don't overuse the same group of muscles. (Thanks [ab2](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/6411/ab2)!)

Comment: Another plus:  you don't overuse one set of muscles.

Comment: `length that will fit` usually logs are sold in 1, 1/2 or 1/3 meter, depending on the size of your chimney. There are equivalence, more or less official, between volumes made of logs of different length. (the shorter the log, the smaller the volume)

Comment: also, before putting those in the fireplace, wait until they are dry. 1-2 year sheltered from the rain should do, depending on the humidity and the type of wood.

Comment: This is exactly the type of answer I was looking for. And it makes complete sense too. Thank you.

Comment: @njzk2 I agree, dry seasoned wood is preferable but in a pinch green wood will work too. 1 meter logs are standard in your area? That feels like something I'd use in a open fireplace in a castle. :) I had a wood stove growing up and we'd use logs around the 12 to 18 inch range which matches your 1/3 to 1/2 meter suggestion.

Comment: @Erik I agree with your sizing. I have a wood stove that is going to be the main use of this wood. 12-18" is the perfect size for the stove.

Comment: @Erik the logs are usually first cut in 1m, then stacked in 1 m3. That 1 m3 is known as a stere, and takes then much less space when cut in half or thirds. People will buy it uncut (1m, but I think that is rare), or cut in 33 or 50 cm.

Comment: @njzk2 interesting. In the United States, or at least where I grew up, wood is commonly sold in a unit called a [cord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cord_%28unit%29).

Comment: Addition to point **3.**: if possible you might consider leaving some piles around as natural habitat for critters like hedgehogs, etc.

Comment: @fgysin I think that depends on lots of factors. Where I grew up people are very concerned about fire danger. Having piles of combustible materials scattered around your property isn't a good idea. Also while hedgehogs are cute and wonderful, wood piles can also attract less pleasant neighbors like skunks and rattlesnakes.

Comment: @Erik: Fair enough. Where I'm from we have no skunks, no dangerous snakes and only very sporadic danger of forest fires. So cute critters all the way! :)